# Magento 1 - Sort cart products / items based on any attribute and group product

Tags: sorting, magento, magento-1.9, cart

I would like to sort products in cart page base on any attribute(like) and Group product wise. 
Anybody having any idea of it ? Please let me know.

Thanks,
Hs

Answer (score 1):

You could do smth like this in your cart template:

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->getCollection()
   ->setQuote($this->getQuote())
   ->addFieldToSelect('name')
   ->addOrder('name', 'asc'); //change acc to your attribute

$items = array();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
   $items[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: I need sorting function for below scenario. 

Customer is adding 3 group products to cart. (Each group products having 4 associated simple products).
Now in shopping cart, all products will display as simple products. But i want them to display by group product wise with sorting by a manufacturer attribute.

Hope you understand my question.